# add custom formatting to Tinymce editor in joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla, editor, tinymce, joomla2.5

I want add a custom format in formatting list in TinyMCE editor.
For example, I want when the user selects text and select my format, Tinymce inserted `<div class="custom">` before selected area,and insert `</div>` after this.

Comment: are you referring to when they highlight the text?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as easy as you hope.
To use custome_formats you may want to have alook at this custom formats example: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php Especially take a look at the "view source" section and inspect the setings formats and style_formats there.